# Place header outside set margins of the page

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

I have to implement some strict guidelines regarding a scholarship application and plan to use the geometry package to achieve this. There is, however, one point I don't understand. The relevant points are:

- Margins must be set at a minimum of 3/4" (1.87 cm)
- Your name and student number must appear outside the set margins of the page (not in header or footer), at the top right corner of every page.

What do they mean by *"outside the set margins"* and their emphasis on *"not in header or footer"*? Isn't the header always outside the set margins of the text body?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the header and/or footer might be included in the text body, and sometimes they might not be part of the text body. The following figure (taken from the documentation of the `geometry` package) shows the page layout in both cases:

[image]

In your situation, the requirements specify that header and footer will not be part of the text body (to be 100% sure, you could ask to the Institution offering the scolarship).

Here's a preliminary document to be used as a starting point, using the `article` document class with the `12pt` (font size) class option, the `geometry` package to design the required page layout, and the `titlesec` package to define the header/footer according to specifications: I placed the page number in the footer and centered, but you can place it whereever it is required.

I also used the `mathptmx`, `helvetic` and `courier` packages to give you the font combination Times/Helvetica/Courier.

Un-commenting the line with the `showframe` option, you'll see frames showing the page layout.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=216mm,paperheight=279mm,margin=1.87cm,marginparsep=0pt%
%,showframe% uncomment to draw a frame showing the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\sethead{}{}{Name -- Number}\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Here's the resulting document:

[image]

Another option, to definitively avoid using the header would be to use the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. Here's a little example, using the `showframe` option for `geometry` to see the space reserved for the header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=216mm,paperheight=279mm,margin=1.87cm,%
marginparsep=0pt,includehead,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgPosition{\textwidth,1}
\SetBgHshift{-63pt}
\SetBgContents{Name --- Number}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: The demands explicitly say that name and number are not to be placed in the header.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: yes, I am aware of that; I don't recall now the reason behind my initial response (but there was a good reason why I opted for that solution). Anyway, I've provided a new solution that avoids using the header.